# mongo remove item in document from array

Tags: mongodb

i have the following document in my collection:

```
"_id" : "12345",
"name" : "test",
    "users" : [
    {
            "name" : "spiderman",
            "email" : "spiderman@spiderman.com",
            "accepted" : true
    },
    {
            "name" : "superman",
            "email" : "superman@superman.com",
            "accepted" : true
    }
]
```

I would like to remove the user superman.

This is what i would like my final result to look like:

```
"_id" : "12345",
"name" : "test",
    "users" : [
    {
            "name" : "spiderman",
            "email" : "spiderman@spiderman.com",
            "accepted" : true
    }
]
```

Ive tried a few things but nothing worked so far. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$pull`

```
db.collection.update(
    { "users.name": "superman" },
    { $pull: { "users": {"name" : "superman"} } },
    { multi: false}
)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer but it gives a error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :